# Updating Gitlab from 9.3.7 to 9.3.8 getting Error installing re2

Tags: ruby, gitlab, updates, re2

We are running on Ubuntu 14.04, with Gitlab 9.3.7, which works fine. We are trying to update to the latest security patch of Gitlab v9.3.8, but it gives us this error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/re2-1.0.0/ext/re2
/usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170720-19622-15i0edf.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lstdc++... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for rb_str_sublen()... yes
checking for main() in -lre2... no
You must have re2 installed and specified with --with-re2-dir, please see https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Install
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-re2-dir
    --without-re2-dir
    --with-re2-include
    --without-re2-include=${re2-dir}/include
    --with-re2-lib
    --without-re2-lib=${re2-dir}/lib
    --with-stdc++lib
    --without-stdc++lib
    --with-re2lib
    --without-re2lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/re2-1.0.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/re2-1.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/re2-1.0.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing re2 (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install re2 -v '1.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  re2
```

The mkmf.log file contains:

```
have_library: checking for main() in -lstdc++... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wall -Wextra -funroll-loops conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wall -Wextra -funroll-loops conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static -lstdc++  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for stdint.h... -------------------- yes

"gcc -E -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wall -Wextra -funroll-loops  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <stdint.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_str_sublen()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wall -Wextra -funroll-loops conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lstdc++  -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static -lstdc++  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_str_sublen; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for main() in -lre2... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wall -Wextra -funroll-loops conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lstdc++  -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static -lre2 -lstdc++  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lre2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wall -Wextra -funroll-loops conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lstdc++  -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static -lre2 -lstdc++  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c:13:13: error: conflicting types for ‘main’
 extern void main();
             ^
conftest.c:5:5: note: previous definition of ‘main’ was here
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
     ^
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10:
11:   return 0;
12: }
13: extern void main();
14: int t(void) { main(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

I've tried adding ruby-dev and ruby2.3-dev as we are using Ruby 2.3. No changes in the update. As this is a fairly recent patch, Gitlab has no further information on their site, and the installation instructions for re2 have not helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problem
It works for me, try it on you own risk

Ubuntu 14.04 have no `libre2-dev`
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/re2

I installed it from sources
https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Install

`cd /tmp
 git clone https://github.com/google/re2.git
 cd re2/
 make
 make test
 sudo checkinstall -D --install=no
 sudo dpkg -i re2_20170720-1_amd64.deb`

And then run
`ldconfig`

Comment: libre2-dev installed without issue on our Ubuntu 14.04. Waiting for a quiet moment to test if Gitlab v9.3.8 with re2 likes this on our VM. Is it safe to assume that the defaults for checkinstall are okay?

Comment: The packages installed in the manner described above work correctly

Comment: Please also follow the wiki page in the answer when error occurs. This answer really works.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to install the re2-gem after installing the lib:

```
apt-get install libre2-dev
```

Comment: We had tried this fix, but 14.04 doesn't appear to have libre2-dev. I've not checked further if it is available in an alternative repository.

Comment: I got the same error on Ubuntu 16.04.
Installing the library as stated in this answer solved the problem for me.

Comment: The same helped me on "debian jessie"

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error on macOS Big Sur. And below installation solve the problem

```
brew install re2
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've just encountered the same error. At least we're not the only one.

I've made an issue in GitLab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/35342

Comment: The same fix is mentioned on the Gitlab issue tracker as @serg-b suggests below. Thanks for posting the bug! I'd started too create a bug and in my sleep deprived mind, never hit submit :(